# Sort users in admin screen by meta value whether it exists or not

Tags: query, user-meta, wp-user-query

I want to list all users and order them by a meta value. Several users have it and some do not, but I want to be able to list them all and group them accordingly. I have the following code but it only selects the users with the meta value and ignores those without it:

```
    function handle_column_sorting( $query ) {
    
        if ( !is_admin() ) {
            return;
        }
    
        if ( isset( $query->query_vars['orderby'] ) && $query->query_vars['orderby'] == 'friend' ) {
    
            $meta_query = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'festival_friend',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'festival_friend',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                    ),
                );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'festival_friend' );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    
            $query->prepare_query();
            
        }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'handle_column_sorting' );
```

A dump of the $query object is below. My SQL knowledge isn't strong enough to figure it out, but it looks wrong to me in that the last bit should read `OR mt2.meta_key IS NULL`. I don't know where I can change that in the query.

```
    [query_fields] => DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS dcw_users.ID
    [query_from] => FROM dcw_users LEFT JOIN dcw_usermeta ON ( dcw_users.ID = dcw_usermeta.user_id )  LEFT JOIN dcw_usermeta AS mt1 ON ( dcw_users.ID = mt1.user_id ) LEFT JOIN dcw_usermeta AS mt2 ON ( dcw_users.ID = mt2.user_id AND mt2.meta_key = 'festival_friend' )
    [query_where] => WHERE 1=1 AND ( dcw_usermeta.meta_key = 'festival_friend' AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'festival_friend' OR mt2.user_id IS NULL ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it only selects the users with the meta value and ignores those
> without it

That's because of this part: `$query->set( 'meta_key', 'festival_friend' );`, which adds an extra clause to the meta query clauses, i.e. the `meta_query` is basically appended with a `array( 'key' => 'festival_friend' )` (yes, an array with just a `key` item). Try `var_dump( $query->meta_query->queries );` and you'd understand what I mean.

So, to fix that, just remove the part I mentioned above. However, you should also set the `orderby` to `meta_value_num`, *if* the meta value is numeric.

Also, you should not re-prepare the query, i.e. `$query->prepare_query()` should not need to be called and instead, use the [`pre_get_users` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_users/) to filter the query args. So,

- Remove this line: `$query->prepare_query();`.
- Replace the `add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'handle_column_sorting' )` with `add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'handle_column_sorting' )`.

---

Your code should now work, however, if you want the users which have the meta `festival_friend` to *always be on the **top** in the list*, specifically when the sort order is `ASC` (i.e. ascending), then try this **after making the above changes**:

1. Set a key for the clauses in your meta query array, e.g. `has_friend` and `no_friend`.

   ```php
   $meta_query = array(
       'relation' => 'OR',

       // Clause 1: Find users having the meta.
       'has_friend' => array(
           'key' => 'festival_friend',
           'compare' => 'EXISTS',
       ),

       // Clause 2: Find users without the meta.
       'no_friend'  => array(
           'key' => 'festival_friend',
           'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
       ),
   );
   ```
2. Add a custom arg named `orderby_friend`, whereby the value is the key of the first clause above.

   ```php
   $query->set( 'orderby_friend', 'has_friend' );
   ```
3. Use this to modify the *`ORDER BY` clause* of the user query.

   ```php
   add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'admin_custom_orderby_friend' );
   function admin_custom_orderby_friend( $query ) {
       if ( ! is_admin() || ! $query->get( 'orderby_friend' ) ) {
           return;
       }

       $clause_key  = $query->get( 'orderby_friend' );
       $clauses_arr = $query->meta_query->get_clauses();

       if ( empty( $clauses_arr[ $clause_key ] ) ) {
           return;
       }

       global $wpdb;

       $order = strtoupper( $query->get( 'order' ) );
       $order = ( 'DESC' === $order ) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

       $alias = $clauses_arr[ $clause_key ]['alias'];

       $query->query_orderby = <<<SQL
   ORDER BY
       # 1. Group the users.
       (CASE
           WHEN ( $alias.meta_key = 'festival_friend' ) THEN 1
           ELSE 2
       END) ASC,
       # 2. Sort them by the meta value.
       $alias.meta_value $order
   SQL;
   }
   ```

**Notes**

- Plugins and themes can also filter the query, hence, instead of hard-coding it, I used [`WP_Meta_Query::get_clauses()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/get_clauses/) to get the *table alias* of the target meta query clause.
- I used the `CASE` operator in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case) / [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/case-operator/) to group the users into 2 groups — one for users having the meta, and the other group for users not having that meta. So the 1st group is at the top and will be sorted by the meta value.
- If the meta value is numeric, you can use `$alias.meta_value+0` instead of `$alias.meta_value`.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful. I was wondering if I should have deleted the `meta_key` bit. I have done the first section of your answer and it now works in that it retrieves all the users. However, the 'Friends' column is now empty in all cases.

Comment: Ignore the above, they are there, they're just grouped in the middle pages for some reason. Might have to implement your second suggestion also.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped, but I should add that if you're specifically targeting just the list table on the admin's users screens, then you should use the [`users_list_table_query_args` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/users_list_table_query_args/) **instead of** `pre_get_users`. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for that, it works well. I only wish I could get them to appear in order of the meta value, they just appear in a clump in the middle whether I want them ascending or descending.